# Problems when writing a post

Tags: css, publish, troubleshooting

I have a blog, with Duena Theme, and when I write is all ok.
The problem is when I publish that text, and the margins of the paragraphs split my words.

For example

The horse is a very wil
d animal and he is eatin
g carrots, salads and lot
s of....

I dont want it to be like that, I don t want my words splitted in half. If it s not enough space, I want all the word to be put down, not parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with css. Look for `word-wrap` and change it to below:

```
.class-name {
    word-wrap: normal;
    -webkit-hyphens: none;
    -moz-hyphens: none;
    hyphens: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is a CSS-specific question.

Somewhere in your stylesheet you have something like the following:

```
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
```

Either set it generally to `none` or just for your desired part of the website, for example, the content wrapper.

**// EDIT**
I just saw you included a sample of how it looks like. Due to the missing hyphens it most probably is `word-wrap: break-word;` somewhere in your styles, as suggested by @Maruti Mohanty. So, fix this with `word-wrap: normal;`.